# Usuário me manda um email com os detalhes da pergunta, como proceder?

Tags: debate, suporte

Nessa pergunta [Mostrar o valor do frete e total com frete](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/435861/mostrar-o-valor-do-frete-e-total-com-frete#comment842905_435861) fiz o seguinte [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/435861/mostrar-o-valor-do-frete-e-total-com-frete#comment842861_435861) pedindo esclarecimento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E o usuário invés de editar a pergunta me manda um [email com os esclarecimentos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/435861/mostrar-o-valor-do-frete-e-total-com-frete#comment842900_435861):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Disse que não abriria e leria o email e que o procedimento [seria editar a pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/435861/mostrar-o-valor-do-frete-e-total-com-frete#comment842905_435861):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Pergunto:

- Foi correta minha atitude ou foi grosseria ignorar o email do usuário?

  - Parece uma coisa boba, mas se foi a atitude correta pergunto como ensinar o usuário a editar uma pergunta? Procurei o tópico [Como editar Minha Pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?page=3&tab=Relevance&q=como%20editar%20minha%20pergunta) e procurei na [central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking) e não encontrei nada padronizado sobre como fazer edições.
  - Caso devesse ter aberto o email, teria eu que editar as informações para o usuário?
- Existe algum tópico com o procedimento para casos onde o usuário use de comunicação pessoal para dar esclarecimentos a perguntas?

Comment: Vou tentar achar uma informação mais oficial e o que mais pode ser feito, mas é isso mesmo. Nada impede você de fazer algo externo ao site, não tem como o site obrigar, mas o mais certo é realmente não fazer isso. Acho que avisá-lo que o que ele fez não é adequado, e no mínimo indelicado. A não ser, claro, se você colocou no seu perfil o e-mail e dizendo para contatar você para qualquer questão.

Comment: @Maniero No perfil coloquei o email para como contato profissional. Também tenho que alimentar as crianças.

Comment: Aí é com você, pode mandar orçamento pra ele :) Você será chamado de mercenário. Recentemente uma pessoa me abordou no Linkedin para fazer uma palestra para os funcionários da empresa dele no RIo. Perguntei de pagamento, ou pelo menos ajuda de custo para ir até la´. Não tinha. E mais, ele disse que ajudou que eu fazia tudo isso pra ajudar, que eu não fazia por dinheiro. Eu falei que faria se fosse um evento para comunidade, algum público, ainda precisaria da ajuda de custo, a não ser que fosse um evento muito forte com público garantidamente qualificado

Comment: o que pelo menos me ajudaria com a renovação do MVP. E ele disse que não sabia que eu fazia por causa de títulos. É, eu sou ruim, eu tenho que fazer tudo de graça pra todo mundo. Não basta o que eu já faço. Mas não sou tão ruim assim porque não perguntei para ele porque ele não dá de graça o trabalho dele para todo mundo. E nunca vi ele fazendo coisa alguma pra comunidade. Aí cai naquilo que o pessoal aqui no meta vive fazendo e diz "eu faço o que eu posso, não tenho culpa que eu posso menos que você". Eu só não falo que pessoas assim deveriam tomar tiro na cabeça porque não é da minha índole.

Comment: Não achei sua conduta errada, e deixei um comentário lá reforçando o que vc disse

Comment: @Maniero Já fui chamado de mercenário no primeiro ano de faculdade escrevi, a mão pois não tinha dinheiro para comprar um computador, o rascunho de um livro sobre Pascal(Turbo Pascal na época) e eu ofereci as cópias do livro entre as classes do curso pois eu queria juntar dinheiro comprar um computador e quem mais podia pagar armou um barraco, duas  ̶v̶e̶l̶h̶a̶s̶ senhoras começaram a chorar e me chamar de mercenário e que eu tinha que da as cópias de graça. Na época eu me senti mal eu era jovem e não sabia nada sobre a vida, se fosse eu teria falado um monte para elas.

Comment: Você está certo temos que lutar pelo que é de nosso interesse. Porque desistir de nossos interesses e se deixar levar pelo ideal de "bondade" alheio o destino é a sarjeta. E se pessoa reclamar o Stack Overflow é a contribuição pro bono.

Comment: @hkotsubo eu gostei da explicação que você colocou para o AP. Acho que ficou bem claro do que se trata fazer uma pergunta no ptSO.

Comment: As pessoas no geral são bastante incoerentes e hipócritas, vemos aqui o tempo todo, se ficar ouvindo essas pessoas sua vida fica um inferno. Hoje eu até me diverto com certas maluquices que aparecem por aqui, não tudo, porque tem caso que passa do limite, mas boa parte é risível de tão doido que é. Uma delas é a quantidade de sinalizações erradas que moderador tem que lidar. Até mensagem do sistema é rude ou ofensiva :D Boa parte é "eu não queria ouvir isso então quero que apague". Democracia é mais sobre ouvir o q não quer do que falar o q quer. Mas parte da sociedade resolveu ser fascistoide

Comment: Comigo ocorre, no facebook também :), quase mandei, *fora do site e das regras R$3000 pela consultoria*, mas seria só pra rir mesmo.

Comment: No meu perfil eu deixei um aviso que no linkedin é só contato profissional, assunto do SOpt tratar no SOpt. Ai dá uma margem melhor pra não retornar. Essa do Guilherme lembrou uma situação de locadora, que o pessoal queria fazer devolução fora de horário (por mais que tivesse contrato e aviso na parede que fechava 23h00) - Foi só por um aviso na campainha de "atendimento fora do horário: acréscimo de R$35,00", com um R$35,00 bem grande, que parou de vez o problema (a multa por devolver no dia seguinte era bem menos que isso).

Comment: Creio que sua atitude foi bem natural para a situação. O usuário confundiu as coisas, provavelmente ele não entendeu o propósito da comunidade e dos que aqui ajudam. A única coisa que faria diferente era ser um pouco mais "delicado" no recado :), pois como escreveu pode soar agressivo para alguns usuários.

Comment: @MateusD. Sua resposta é util, acho que deveria mante-lá. Pois é o seu ponto de vista e é válido.

Comment: @AugustoVasques reativei, obrigado pelo feed. =D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema ao meu ver vai além do usuário estar começando na plataforma, a questão é como a plataforma é vista lá fora e como alguns usuários que bancam de HELPDESKER fazem essa imagem se propagar dentro e fora da comunidade.

Atualmente nós temos duas famas:

1. Somos sites de soluções prontas, Ctrl+C e Ctrl+V, e excelentes textos ficam perdidos no meio da falta de entendimento ou preguiça de quem chega a pouco e só quer copiar e nem liga pra aprender de verdade
2. Somos um consultoria, suporte ou qualquer coisa assim que vamos fazer sua lição de casa ou resolver o seu problema do começo ao fim, mesmo que você tenha pulado o básico, pois tem que gente que nem `IF` sabe usar, programa no "chute", "se funcionar, funcionou", etc... Inclusive esses dias falei com um usuário expliquei sobre IFs e mesmo assim no final ele fez errado e por coincidência funcionou"

Esses 2 problemas, principalmente o segundo fazem o usuário chegar aqui e achar de fato de que trabalhamos de graça e que somos obrigados sim a fazer o que pedem, porque é assim que enxergam a plataforma, não só dentro da plataforma, mas talvez até no mundo afora, aonde tantos vivem de gambiarras e se acham mestres da programação e até propagam gambiarras afirmando ser o certo, vou então logo dizendo:

- Não somos a plataforma [*Stack Overflow Jobs*](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs)
- Dispomos nosso tempo de graça sim, mas não trabalhamos de graça
- O site, infelizmente por culpa de muitos (no SOen e no SOpt também), criou uma péssima imagem
- As pessoas acham que programação ou até mesmo outras áreas de TI é como ser médico ou advogado, a pessoa acredita que vai estudar um tempo de nada e já vai ganhar rios de dinheiro, mas acabam falhando miseravelmente e ficam procurando babás para fazer o que elas são muitas vezes incompetentes, não estou falando dos novatos, estou falando de muitas pessoas que estão a mais de 2 anos na área e vêm no site só pedir suporte técnico (o nome de um desses usuários virou até piada interna)
- Os novatos vêm aqui com a desculpa, estou me acostumando com a plataforma, bem eu me acostumei em poucos dias e vejo gente fazendo errado durante meses, mas da forma que afirmam parece que as pessoas de 5 anos atrás tem a mente diferente das pessoas atuais na área de TI e que as pessoas a 5 anos atrás liam as regras, entendiam e se adaptavam e as de hoje são extremamente lentas e a maioria deve sofrer de déficit de atenção (TDA), porque é a única explicação que parece plausível (sim estou sendo irônico). De qualquer forma o [Help](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help) esta ai, tem links, quando a pergunta é fechada o motivo esta evidente e mesmo assim as pessoas parece que não conseguem entender e por causa disto uma série de discussões surgem e a culpa é sempre de quem deveria "trabalhar de graça" (aparentemente como o site é visto).

Em resumo eu vou ser sincero, eu devo tenho um numero considerável de "amigos" no facebook e contatos no linkedin que me adicionaram pra eu dar suporte exclusivo, essas pessoas realmente ou estão começando ou realmente tem a ideia errada e querem babás, as pessoas podem até argumentar que estou sendo exagerado, mas qualquer um que tenha bom senso se soubesse se por no lugar da pessoa que ela esta pedindo ajuda entenderia que:

- Tempo é dinheiro
- Conhecimento nem sempre é de graça
- Se algo é difícil é porque a outra pessoa teve que estudar
- Se quer exclusivo, pague

Eu duvido que qualquer uma dessas pessoas que costumam pedir ajuda iriam dispor do seu tempo ou trabalhar de graça para outra pessoa ganhar vantagens, isso me lembra até o caso de um usuário (vamos chama-lo de `usuário Beta`) que veio no site pedindo ajuda, e um colega ajudou bastante (vamos chama-lo de `usuário Alpha`), acho que a ajuda se estendeu bastante além, se tornando um "helpdesk".

Passado um tempo (foi um dia apenas se me recordo) o patrão do `usuário Beta` mandou uma mensagem ou email para o `usuário Alpha` desabafando, se me recordo ele tinha dito que acreditava ter contratado uma pessoa capacitada, mas na verdade contratou uma pessoa que o "iludiu", pois quem resolveu o problema foi o `usuário Alpha`.

Eu não estou dizendo que uma pessoa sem experiência não deva ser contratada, o que estou dizendo é que toda essa situação de Helpdesk no site, seja dentro ou fora geralmente é um **"engodo"**, pois já vi muitas vezes pessoas em meio de prova, para entrevistas ou durante aula ou para aula do dia seguinte buscando suporte aqui no site, e vi gente ajudando.

A plataforma deveria ser para levar conhecimento, com perguntas que sirvam para o usuário atual e futuros visitantes da mesma pergunta, mas muitas perguntas, incrivelmente e atualmente a maioria, andam só servido de helpdesk mesmo, dentro e fora do site e tem muitos usuários do site que apoiam isso, sem notar as vezes.

O que eu disse antes **não é opinião**, é de observação, são ocorrências corriqueiras, agora o que vou dizer a seguir é minha opinião:

> Seja educado e diga que só atende no site, se reclamarem dizendo que fecharam a pergunta então faça o mínimo razoável e educadamente diga que fora do site e fora das regras você cobra, pois ninguém deve ser obrigado a trabalhar de graça.

Answer (score 1):

Analisando a publicação, acredito que sua reação é no mínimo justificável.

Em contrapartida, não creio que ele tenha agido com má intenção. Nitidamente se trata de uma pessoa que está iniciando na plataforma e até nos estudos com desenvolvimento talvez, e nesse pouco tempo que estou procurando ser mais ativo dentro da comunidade já me deparei com algumas respostas um pouco "desnecessárias" da parte do pessoal mais experiente com novos usuários, não digo que esse foi o seu caso, mas acredito que nesse tipo de situação a primeira solução deve ser tentar "educar" a pessoa para entender como funciona o sistema, se ela persistir no erro, ai não tem jeito infelizmente.

Eu mesmo estou me adaptando, cometo erros de vez em quanto, mas tento levar em consideração os comentários feitos pelos usuários e moderadores, mas uma pessoa que está começando levar um *baque* desses pode fazer ela desanimar, e creio que não seja esse o objetivo do SOpt.

Em resumo, creio que sua atitude foi correta, pois você não é obrigado a dar um "atendimento exclusivo" para nenhum usuário fora da plataforma, e até ignorar o e-mail não considero nenhum absurdo, a única coisa que eu faria diferente talvez seria a maneira com que isso foi passado para o AP.

Answer (score 0):

Cara, no meu [perfil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/8063/sam?tab=profile) eu informo meu contato WhatsApp, e já recebi muitos contatos de usuários do site, não apenas pedindo ajuda sobre perguntas postadas por eles mas até solicitações em resolver ou desenvolver programação em troca de remuneração.

Aí vai a critério seu. Eu não gosto de ser mercenário e explorar as pessoas. Quando é algo que eu consiga resolver de forma fácil, eu não cobro nada, mas se vejo que vai dar um certo trabalho, eu passo um orçamento. Vai de caso a caso.

Em relação à qualidade da pergunta, eu sempre busco orientar o usuário a melhorar pergunta se for o caso, mas se vejo que é algo muito complexo e que seja necessário contratar um profissional, eu falo isso tudo ao usuário, e o oriento, dependendo do caso, a melhorar a pergunta ou excluí-la e contratar meus serviços (isso fora do site), e se mesmo melhorando a pergunta ele não irá conseguir resolver o problema (quando são coisas muito complexas. Já houve casos assim. Às vezes o usuário acha que fazendo uma pergunta no site irá resolver tudo que ele quer, mas a complexidade é muito maior).

Em relação ao seu caso, não custava nada ler o e-mail que ele te mandou (afinal, você publicou seu e-mail no seu [perfil](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/137387/augusto-vasques?tab=profile)), e, como eu disse, não apenas responder ao e-mail enviado como também orientá-lo sobre as políticas de qualidade de perguntas no site. Você teria feito duas coisas úteis: uma boa participação no site e quem sabe teria fechado um bom negócio valorizando seus conhecimentos.

Ao meu ver você foi indelicado em ignorar o e-mail (e podia ter fechado um bom negócio) e não há nada nas políticas do site que te impeça de ter contato pessoal com outros usuários. Você só não pode fazer propaganda ou informar contato nos tópicos (perguntas e respostas).

Comment: Obrigado pelo ponto de vista. Vou refletir a respeito.

Comment: Essa é plataforma de pro bono. Se eu quisesse fazer freelance procuraria uma plataforma especializada, tem o get ninjas, o stackoverflow jobs,...